# Selenium windows Handle Return

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to get windows handles. Now something which am curious is on the return type of Handles. Is there a possibility that Handles might return duplicate values and hence they have made it to return Set instead of List. My Initial Assumptions are windows handle might return duplicate values. I feel that it returns Set and not Map because of having two parameters key and values. So they would have made it return a simple Set.

Answer (score 1):

`getWindowHandles()` is returning `Set<String>` only in Java. In C# `WindowHandles` returns `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` which is wrapper to `List<string>`.

Window handles can't be duplicated as they are unique identifier for the open windows.